# Ajax request not works when more files uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, jquery-file-upload

This is my function before image upload it shows loading when success it shows files. 
but if file length are more like 20 or 40 it uploads file but the data not shown in the console and only loading images shown in the browser

```
function upload_images(self)
{

    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('_token', $('input[name="_token"]').val());
    var holder = $('div.pond div.pond-img-list'); //uploaded files holder
    var formdata_file_length = 0;
    var allowed_file_type = ['image/gif', 'image/jpeg','image/jpg','image/png'];

    for(var i = 0; i<self.files.length; i++)
    {
        if(in_array(self.files[i].type, allowed_file_type))
        {
            formdata.append('images[]', self.files[i]);
            formdata_file_length++;
        }
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '/upload/images',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formdata,
        mimeTypes: "multipart/form-data",
        async: true,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function(){
            for(var i = 0; i < formdata_file_length; i++)
            {
                holder.append('<div class="pond-img col-md-3">'+
                    '<div class="pond-img-thumb-container">'+
                        '<a target="_blank"><img class="pond-img-thumb" src="/uploads/web/loading.svg"></a>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="pond-img-actions">'+
                        '<a class="pond-img-delete" href="#" title="Silmək"></a>'+
                        '<a class="pond-img-rotate" href="">↻</a>'+
                        '<a class="pond-img-rotate" href="">'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>');
            }
        },
        success: function(data){

            console.log(data);

            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                holder.children('.pond-img').eq(i).children('.pond-img-thumb-container')
                    .children('a').children('img').attr('src', '/'+data[i]);
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            // holder.children('.img-loading').remove();
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Try add `error: function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown)` instead of just `error: function()`, and then log `jqxhr`, `textStatus` and `errorThrown` to console, to see if any errors exists.

Comment: @eli [object Object] , parsererror SyntaxError, Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: The object (jqxhr), might have some responseText (jqxhr.responseText). It could hold some more information on the error, so try log it to console as well (or better, write it to some tag in your HTML body, as it could hold _a lot_ of information).

Comment: I found the solution. the problem was with php. Thanks @eli

Comment: Alright, was it the responseText that gave you the hint, or did you manage to find an answer for a similar question somewhere else?

Comment: yeah little bit your answer gave me idea and i looked somewhere else. Thanks you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. 
There is nothing wrong with ajax.
Needed to change the max_file_upload and post_max_size=0 in php.ini.
And check which php.ini you change because there are different php version folder
in your php folder. command line check php version **php -v**